# setting forwarding email address for user

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, email-forwarding

Is there anyway at this time to update a users forwarding email address using graph api in O365.

If not are there any plans in place to allow this in the future.

Comment: Can you give example of what you are trying to achieve and what exactly do you mean by "update users forwarding address"?

Comment: right now with our in-house software  when we are onboarding students into our sis and lms systems we create their O365 accounts and set their mail forwarding initially to forward all email to their personal accounts they provided and we do this with Powershell scripts that we run via c#.                                                         I am sure i would be able to set it with the office api but i would love to be able to use the graph api do to this.